# How to remove all null space with vim

Tags: vim

```
0000
1111

2222
3333

4444
5555
```

Such a file, how to remove all null space lines with vim like this:

```
0000
1111
2222
3333
4444
5555
```

Comment: @loganrakai Yes. They are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`:global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_10.html#10.4) will help:

```
:g/^$/d
```

The part between `//` is the regexp to search for (empty line) and `d` is the command - delete the line.